# status: 405, statusText: "Method Not Allowed", in axios .post laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

i am trying to do axios.post method for sending the messages . But i am getting this error repeatedly.

my script looks like this

```
sendMsg(){
            if(this.msgFrom){
               axios.post('messages/sendMessage/',{
                   conID:this.conID,
                   msg:this.msgFrom
               })
                   .then(response => {
                       console.log('saved successfully');

                   })
                   .catch(function (error) {
                       console.log(error.response);
                   });
            }
        }
```

Route looks like this

```
Route::post('/messages/sendMessage','Messages@sendmsg');
```

and controller looks like this

```
public function sendmsg(Request $request){
        echo $request->msg;
   }
```

and i am getting the error code 405,method not allowed , any solutions please.

Comment: try axios.post('/messages/sendMessage/'... . put a slash before message

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make an assumption:

- Your route is currently in the default `api.php` file

So you may need to modify your URL in the axios request to include the `/api/`:

`/api/messages/sendMessage`